# How to put base64 video Url on amazon s3 url usign axios

Tags: reactjs, base64, axios

I have tried following code, please take this as example

```
var options = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'media/mp4' }};
var video_buffer = new Buffer(videoBase64string);
var data = {
    Key: signedVideoKey, 
    Body: video_buffer,
    ContentEncoding: 'base64'
};

axios.put(signedVideoUrl, data, options).then((resp) => {
  alert('Video has been uploaded.')
}
```

Comment: why my question is not correct actually i am new to stack overflow. There is no error produces by API but uploaded video become corrupt and not playing in player

Comment: you have not described the context, what you want to achieve and what the problem is. This way it is unclear how we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Here is an complete example how to upload my files on S3 signed url. Here i realized that we don't need to upload base64url just completely upload file without encoding.

Many thanks to Medium. Here you can read more about this
https://medium.com/@kevinwu/client-side-file-upload-to-s3-using-axios-c9363ec7b530

```
var React = require('react');
var Dropzone = require('react-dropzone');
var axios = require('axios');

exports = module.exports = React.createClass({
  _onDrop: function (files) {
    var file = files[0];

    axios.get(ENDPOINT_TO_GET_SIGNED_URL, {
      filename: file.name,
      filetype: file.type
    })
    .then(function (result) {
      var signedUrl = result.data.signedUrl;

      var options = {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': file.type
        }
      };

      return axios.put(signedUrl, file, options);
    })
    .then(function (result) {
      console.log(result);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <Dropzone onDrop={ this._onDrop } size={ 150 }>
        <div>
          Drop some files here!
        </div>
      </Dropzone>
    );
  }
});
```